# Summation of element of a subset and divition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $n\in \Bbb N $, $A\subset \Bbb N $ , $|A|=n$ then there exist subset of $A$ such that $8$ divides summation of its element .

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? This is clearly not true if $n=1$, for instance.

Comment: Technically, it is true: the empty set is always a subset of $A$ and 8 divides 0.

Comment: @Fixee: Yes, I suppose that that **could** be the point of the question. From the [tag:elementary-number-theory] tag I was unconsciously expecting something a little more substantial.

Comment: Are you sure you read this right? $n$ is somewhat useless here as the statement can be rephrased "every nonempty set $A \subset \Bbb N$ contains a subset whose sum is divisible by 8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok with the comments, lets suppose $n\geq 8$ and the subset not empty ...

Let $A=\{x_1,...x_n\}$, we define $f(i) = (\sum_{j=1}^i x_j) \mod 8$

Since $n\geq 8$ there exists $1\leq n_1<n_2\leq n$ such that $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$ hence $$(\sum_{j=n_1}^{n_2-1} x_j)=0[8]$$or there exist $n'$ such that $f(n')=0$ and you have your subset.

I hope it helps

Comment: I think your two added assumptions are reasonable enough to make the original question interesting.  But 8 feels quite arbitrary now.